24.04 - KVM Switch logoff session
I use a KVM Switch to switch between Windows and Ubuntu machines.
When I switch away from Ubuntu to windows and then back the Ubuntu session is locked and all apps that were running are closed.
I tried a lot of tips from Ask Ubuntu but nothing solved the problem.

the same question (or very similar) was asked here too and the best advise was to file a bug report. Note that bugs are off topic here

This question is similar to: How do I report a bug?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The problem is solved by installing the newest release 24.04.1
